# Error while creating the activity in Forge [Critical]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I am facing error while creating the activity from 2 days.
We haven't done any changes in the program and have already deployed it in a Production Machine where its working fine from 3-4 months. Also tried to run the same on my machine but same error is coming.

Please help me out with this issue as its critical (currently being used in production with Forge Subscription)...

The error from the log is shown below for your reference.

```
03-10-2020 11:44:14:    Checking if activity DGActivity1 exists...
03-10-2020 11:44:14:    Creating new version for activity DGActivity1...
03-10-2020 11:44:14:    Error reported: Exception creating activity version.
03-10-2020 11:44:14:    Response status: BadRequest
03-10-2020 11:44:14:    Response details: {"commandLine":["Invalid switch [$(appbundles[DGApplication1].path)]. Variables that expand to paths must be quoted. (Parameter 'commandLine')"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting October 1st, an activity definition requires argument and appbundles path variables be quoted as mentioned in the response details. An announcement was made 5 months ago. Please refer to this [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-command-line).

If your old command line was defined like this

```
$(engine.path)\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i $(args[InventorDoc].path) /al $(appbundles[SomeApp].path) /s $(settings[script].path)
```

You may fix it with:

```
$(engine.path)\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i "$(args[InventorDoc].path)" /al "$(appbundles[SomeApp].path)" /s $(settings[script].path)
```

Comment: Okay thanks! We cross checked the post activity HTTP API Reference and updated immediately according to it.